# Can anyone help me edit a boolean with check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Everything is working fine in my rails project, except for one thing. I'm trying to be able to edit a boolean with check_box. But when I go to edit, whether or not the check_box is checked, the boolean stays false. Here is my relevant code:

```
class SubnetsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /subnets
  # GET /subnets.json
  def index
    @subnets = Subnet.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @subnets }
    end
  end

  def normal
    @subnets = Subnet.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # normal.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @subnets }
    end
  end

  # GET /subnets/1
  # GET /subnets/1.json
  def show
    @subnet = Subnet.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @subnet }
    end
  end

  # GET /subnets/new
  # GET /subnets/new.json
  def new
    @subnet = Subnet.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @subnet }
    end
  end

  # GET /subnets/1/edit
  def edit
    @subnet = Subnet.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /subnets
  # POST /subnets.json
  def create
    @subnet = Subnet.new(params[:subnet])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subnet.save
        format.html { redirect_to @subnet, :notice => 'Subnet was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @subnet, :status => :created, :location => @subnet }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @subnet.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /subnets/1
  # PUT /subnets/1.json
  def update
    @subnet = Subnet.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subnet.update_attributes(params[:subnet])
        format.html { redirect_to @subnet, :notice => 'Subnet was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @subnet.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /subnets/1
  # DELETE /subnets/1.json
  def destroy
    @subnet = Subnet.find(params[:id])
    @subnet.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to subnets_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@subnet) do |f| %>
  <% if @subnet.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subnet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subnet from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @subnet.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :SubnetName %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :SubnetName %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :FW_Context_BridgeGroup %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :FW_Context_BridgeGroup %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :VlanNumber %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :VlanNumber %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :FwVlan %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :FwVlan %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :NetAddress %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :NetAddress %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :DefaultRouter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :DefaultRouter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Netmask %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Netmask %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Broadcast %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Broadcast %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Notes %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :Notes %>
  </div>
  **<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :multicast %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :multicast %>
  </div>**
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Migration:

```
class AddMulticast < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :subnets, :multicast, :boolean, :default => 0
  end

  def down
    remove_column :subnets, :multicast
  end

end
```

I know I'm probably missing some small piece of code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: show us your whole form and controller, please.

Comment: try `:checked => true or :checked => 'checked'` if value is true

Comment: nash, I added the rest of that code.

Amar, I tried both as such:
<%= f.check_box :multicast, :checked => true %>
and:
<%= f.check_box :multicast, :checked => 'checked' %>

neither seemed to work. Did I do it right?

Comment: are you sure you have defined the field `multicast` as boolean in your migration file? if it is define as string it won't work...

Comment: Yes, multicast was defined as a boolean.

Comment: PS: You should not use names starting with uppercase letter for attributes... `Notes`, should be `notes`, etc... maybe your `multicast` has been defined as `Multicast` in your migration... please include your migration file

Comment: Have you verified that the value in the db is true using the Rails Console?

Comment: The uppercase was not my choice. I normally would have them lower case, but when I originally made the project with a scaffold they were automatically capitalized. Maybe because I capitalized them in the scaffold, but I followed the guide online and that's exactly what they had. I've also included my migration now...and thanks for the downvotes, I've done nothing but politely ask a question and given everything you've asked for, but whatever.

Comment: Sorry everybody, I got it working! I had a couple different projects going, and I swear I had the attribute in the model...but when I just checked, it was not. It is now working perfectly. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
add_column :subnets, :multicast, :boolean, :default => 0
```

what you mean by `default => 0`?
Boolean can get two values: `true` and `false`... `0` and `false` are not the same...

You should remove the `:default => 0` or use the below:

```
:multicast, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
```

Comment: I already fixed it, but thank you! I have since removed the default => 0. I'm not sure if that was part of the problem, as all it did was default every multicast to 0 which corresponds to false. If you look in the comments, I mention how I somehow missed adding multicast to the model.